# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor a_k(x)\right\rfloor}{10^k}=\frac{x}{19}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $a(x)$ be the sequence defined as
>   $$a_1(x)=\frac x2\\a_{n+1}(x)=\frac{20a_n(x)-19\left\lfloor a_n(x)\right\rfloor}{2}$$
>   for all $x,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor a_k(x)\right\rfloor}{10^k}=\frac{x}{19}$$

The first thing I have tried is to group terms of given sum. However, it is very hard because of floor function inside it. My second attempt is to use induction because $x$ is natural number. After many attempts, I could'n prove it using this approach.
Then I decided to expand $\frac x{19}$ in some way and try to get above sum from that. I wrote $\frac x{19}$ as
$$\frac{x}{19}=\frac{\frac x{20}}{1-\frac1{20}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x}{20^k}$$
Now I only need to prove that this sum is equal to above sum. I have tried to group and cancel out some terms, but I could get rid of floor function. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Try writing $\frac{19}{20}\frac{\lfloor a_n \rfloor}{10^n} = \frac{a_{n}}{10^n} - \frac{a_{n+1}}{10^{n+1}}$ and sum this up using that the right hand side telescopes.

Comment: As I said, I was sure I have missed something very obvious. This simply solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you also need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{10^n} = 0$ for this argument to work. This you can do by writing $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{19}{2}(a_n - [a_n]) \leq \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{19}{2}$.

Comment: @Winther. I have already proved that this series converges, which means that last term must be $0$.

Comment: Great. Since you know how to solve it in detail it might be a good idea to write it up as an answer then (you can answer your own question).